# getting error `This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment` in chrome

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, webpack

I am working on an app running Angularjs 1.4. This morning the app started crashing wit the below error when I updated my Chrome browser to `Version 83.0.4103.61`

Seems like it does not accept innerHTML anymore.

[image]

Edit: I figured out it has something to do with our CSP policies especially `require-trusted-types-for 'script';`

With the new chrome update, it seems to have become stricter.

Comment: I would like to know this too, there isn't much information online. Font Awesome is failing for me due to this

Comment: Back link to Angular repository, with explanations : https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/32353

Answer (score 13):

@Doubidou method uses `default`, which is going to disable TrustedHTML assignment (CSP) protection.

The way bellow isn't going to disable the protection. We are creating a trust policy that is going to return the same as the input.

```js
escapeHTMLPolicy = trustedTypes.createPolicy("forceInner", {
    createHTML: (to_escape) => to_escape
})
```

Then just prepare your html codes before any input:

```js
my_element.innerHTML = escapeHTMLPolicy.createHTML("<h1>your_html</h1>");
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TrustedHTML

Comment: I now get another error:
`Policy "forceInner" disallowed`

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because of a scraping issue with python/selenium on a recent recaptcha build, here is the solution using @Benjamin Walter Mauss's answer above:

```
driver.execute_script(f'''const escapeHTMLPolicy = trustedTypes.createPolicy("forceInner", {{createHTML: (to_escape) => to_escape}});
        document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = escapeHTMLPolicy.createHTML("{recaptcha_token}");''')
```

note I'm doubling the bracket in the javascript function to escape them for f-string formatting