# Chrome devtools - can I load a CDN file from console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, cdn

Can I load a CDN file from Chrome devtools console?

Background:

- I get this question when I am experimenting with web3 javascript from console.
- This question is about the console usage.

I have a web3 java script below.
You don't need to read the whole script as my question is only about the first CDN script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Using web3 API with MetaMask</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.8.2/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                if (window.ethereum) {
                    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
                    ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log("Ethereum enabled");
    
                            web3.eth.getAccounts(function (err, acc) {
                                if (err != null) {
                                    self.setStatus("There was an error fetching your accounts");
                                    return;
                                }
                                if (acc.length > 0) {
                                    console.log(acc);
                                }
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            console.warn('User didn\'t allow access to accounts.');
                            waitLogin();
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log("Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider installing MetaMask.");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    </html>
```

The HTML and inside script work well in browser.
Now I want to experiment it from Chrome Devtools Console, line by line.
I stumped at the first task, how to load that CDN script from the console?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.8.2/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

First, I tried the following (suggested by [How to include JavaScript file or library in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228))

```
> document.head.innerHTML += '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.8.2/dist/web3.min.js"></script>'
```

error:

```
VM70:1 This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment.
```

Then I tried the solution in the above link, in console,

```
> var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.8.2/dist/web3.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

error:

```
VM216:3 This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment.
```

The mentioned post was 11 years ago, likely security feature changed and caused the error.

At last, I tried the following in console (suggested by [getting error `This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment` in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964265)). Now I use trustedTypes hoping to rid the security/policy error.

```
> escapeHTMLPolicy = trustedTypes.createPolicy("forceInner", {
            createHTML: (to_escape) => to_escape
        })
var script = escapeHTMLPolicy.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.8.2/dist/web3.min.js';
escapeHTMLPolicy.head.appendChild(script);
```

error:

```
Refused to create a TrustedTypePolicy named 'forceInner' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "trusted-types parse-html-subset sanitize-inner-html static-types lottie-worker-script-loader webui-test-script webui-test-html print-preview-plugin-loader polymer-html-literal polymer-template-event-attribute-policy".
```

The mentioned post was recent but was not done from console. That may be why it didn't help me.

Is it possible to load CDN from devtools console?

- I tried to understand how devtools works, comparing to the normal
  browser navigation.
- The html page didn't have any special security or policy settings, but worked.
- Why I cannot do it from console?
- I have searched StackOverflow and other places but none of the search result are for console.

Environment:

- windows 10, latest patch
- chrome latest, Version 110.0.5481.178 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @wOxxOm, I added the document.createElement test. It failed. That was why I didn't mention it in early post. Sorry for this. I could have been more clear about this.

Comment: I see the error was TrustedScriptURL. I guess you'll need to reuse the site's policy stored in a global variable, otherwise you'll have to strip this header from the site's response by using an extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm, the error is: "VM216:3 This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment.". I have added this into my post. thank you

Comment: You sounds like have a solution. Can you spell out the detail? I am learning this part; I cannot follow what you suggested. Thank you

Comment: Try the [existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=TrustedScriptURL) for this error first.

Comment: What's the full URL of the public page where you're trying to use the JS console?

Comment: @jsejcksn, you are on the spot. I was using Chrome "Add New Tab", the "+", button. In the new tab's console, I got the "This document requires Trusted..." error. But when I set URL to google.com, document.createElement worked. Thank you

Comment: What’s a “*web 3 Java script*”?

Comment: @DavidThomas npm/web3@1.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some clue from @jsejcksn's comment in the open post.

If I used New Tab's console, I would got errors in my open post.
[image]

But If I go to google.com, then open devtools console, all worked out.
[image]

In particular, I tested

```
> document.head.innerHTML += '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.8.2/dist/web3.min.js"></script>'
```

and

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.8.2/dist/web3.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

both worked.